# Check if there is sub-url in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, indexof, window.location

I need to check if there is sub-page in url?

Something like this

**www.example.com**

```
alert ('This is root of website');
```

**www.example.com/about.html**

```
alert('This is not root of website');
```

How to alert only when if user is root of website, main page?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `window.location.pathname` to get the pathname of current URL:

```
if(window.location.pathname.length > 1) {
    alert('This is not root of website');
} else {
    alert ('This is root of website');
}
```

Comment: No error, but i dont need else, i only need when is in root to alert

Answer (score 0):

Try `location` global object. Use its `pathname` property:

```
alert( location.pathname );
```

So use something like below

```
if (location.pathname == "/") {
    alert("Homepage");
} else {
    alert("not homepage");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "www.example.com/about.html";

if(url.split("/")[1] != ""){

  // sub url present
}

else{

// not present
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(location.pathname.length>1){
alert('This is not root of website');
}
else{
alert ('This is root of website');
}
```